# Get ID of FeedItem

Tags: chatter, feeditem, chatter-feed

I am using a trigger to get the content of the latest chatter post to send it to an external application, however I am having difficulty getting the ID of the FeedItem.

post.Body returns the body of the chatter message as expected, however post.Id returns null.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the chatter feed against a custom object or a standard object like an account? Also can you share more of your trigger code.

Comment: In a "before insert" FeedItem trigger, the FeedItem ID will be null because the insert hasn't occurred. (All triggers behave this way.)

Comment: Here is my trigger code:

`trigger MLPostTrigger on FeedItem (before insert) {

    List<FeedItem> posts = Trigger.new;
    
    MLPost.MLPostCreate(posts);
}
`

Comment: It completely makes sense that a before insert trigger would have a null id. Are there implications to changing the trigger to after insert?